# Extraction of GMT Time difference

Tags: javascript

I have a date variable.

```
var d = new Date();
//Fri Nov 21 2014 15:07:30 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

If i have to extract only GMT+0530 from the date, is there any built in Javascript libraries of function for this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the timezone offset?

```
var d = new Date();
d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

[Mozilla Docs: Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: This will be in minutes right, Can i directly obtain in hours format or should i convert it myself.

Comment: See the examples section of the resource I posted. There is an example for your case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core%5FJavaScript%5F1.5%5FReference/Global%5FObjects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) :

```
var d = new Date();
var gmt = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: To get it in hour : var gmt_in_hour = d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;